# After clearing document, document.write(ln) won't work?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, document.write

as in title says I have a problem, here is example:

```
...    
<script>
document.body.innerHTML = "";
document.write("<scr"+"ipt>alert(1);<\/scr"+"ipt>");
</script>
```

After clearing document, I want to write in it some JS code (and I want to be executed of course). I have tried other methods but it seems that they won't work (and I have browser Firefox 6.0).

Does anyone know solution or working alternative for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the script positioned? If it is in the `head` it does not work because `document.body` is `null`. The `body` of the document was not parsed yet.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `document.write()`. Just don't. (See [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice))

---

Try this:

```
var text = 'alert(1);',
    script = document.createElement('script');
script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

document.write only works before the DOM is loaded; document.body.innerHTML only works after.

Try using document.body.appendChild to append a new text node instead.

Comment: You can access `document.body` even if the DOM is not fully parsed (but only inside `body` not inside `head`).

Comment: Well, that is a different question ;)